# Multiple Enrichers fail in Mule Flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio

The problem is that I have two Enrichers which are alternately called based on the payload type.  Class Foo calls an SAP function module and Class Bar calls a different function module.  A Choice router checks the payload type and routes accordingly, and correctly.

When the sub-flows return to the enricher, the enrichers work--EXCEPT in this repeatable scenario.

From a browser, if I access the HTTP-endpoint, with the URL that works class Foo, it works perfectly.  If I "stop" the mule server (localhost), and start it again, I can then call the HTTP-endpoint with the URL that works class Bar.  Also, it works perfectly.

But, what I cannot do is leave the mule app running, and alternate the calls from the browser.  The wrong enricher is executed from the sub-flows when you select a second url that causes a different routing.

To summarize:

1. Call Foo url over and over just fine, and then call Bar url--it
   fails.
2. Stop/Restart Server
3. Call Bar url over and over just fine, and then call Foo url--it
   fails.

Below is the NullPointerException we get.  The stacktrace is an example of Scenario 1.  I've called the Foo url one-or-more times, and then called Bar url.  The payload type is Bar, but the Enricher that mule is trying to invoke is from the Foo enricher which is null.

```
    ERROR 2015-07-18 07:33:35,296 [[vistaar].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "payload.bapiFunction=__object_for_enrichment" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: Bar
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.mvel2.DataConversion:129 (null)
2. error calling method: com.company.foo.**Foo.**setBapiFunction (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.SetterAccessor:46 (null)
3. Execution of the expression "payload.bapiFunction=__object_for_enrichment" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:202 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
4. Execution of the expression "payload.bapiFunction=__object_for_enrichment" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: **Bar** (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.mvel2.DataConversion.convert(DataConversion.java:129)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.SetterAccessor.setValue(SetterAccessor.java:25)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.SetterAccessor.setValue(SetterAccessor.java:41)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Here are my flows...

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="payload.getObjectList()" counterVariableName="count">

<expression-component doc:name="Build Bapi Pojo"><![CDATA[payload.buildBapiFunction();]]></expression-component>

    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="payload is com.mycompany.project.Foo">
            <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[payload.bapiFunction]" doc:name="Enrich w/Sales Deal RFC results">
                <flow-ref name="sales-deal-rfc-flow" doc:name="RFC" />
            </enricher>
        </when>
        <when expression="payload is com.mycompany.project.Bar">
            <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[payload.bapiFunction]" doc:name="Enrich w/Price Struct RFC results">
                <flow-ref name="price-struct-rfc-flow" doc:name="RFC" />
            </enricher>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="#['Should never be here.']" level="INFO" doc:name="Impossible" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>

</foreach>
```

```
<sub-flow name="sales-deal-rfc-flow" doc:name="sales-deal-rfc-flow">

    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Pojo_To_Xml" doc:name="Pojo To Xml" />

    <sap:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="SAP" type="function" functionName="ZFM_OPROI1110_SDCR"
        xmlVersion="2" outputXml="true" evaluateFunctionResponse="true" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SAP" />

    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_To_Pojo" doc:name="Xml To Pojo" />

</sub-flow>


<sub-flow name="price-struct-rfc-flow" doc:name="price-struct-rfc-flow">

    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Pojo_To_Xml_1" doc:name="Pojo To Xml" />

    <sap:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="SAP" type="function" functionName="ZFM_OPROI1105_PS" xmlVersion="2" outputXml="true"
        evaluateFunctionResponse="true" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SAP" exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_To_Pojo_1" doc:name="Xml To Pojo" />

</sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged this to verify the payload class before executing choice router? Is it indeed Bar class when called thru Bar URL (re-scenario 1)? If yes, maybe `is` is not working as expected. Have you tried with `instanceof` instead?

Comment: The payload is definitely the correct payload (class).  I also tried surrounding the Message Enricher inside a Processor Chain--same result.   I tried having the enricher update a variable, and then add a separa.3te step to update my original payload class.

Comment: I also tried to update different variables for each Message Enricher.... all the same.  I just tried instanceof vs is.  Routing is happening properly.  I've verified that several ways (debugger, loggers dumping #[payload.class]  etc..

Comment: That's a weird behavior. If you still experiencing this, try and see if removing the mule expression tag fixes it. For example, `<enricher source="payload" target="payload.bapiFunction" doc:name="Enrich w/Sales Deal RFC results">`

Comment: We have submitted this problem to Mulesoft Support.  They have acknowledged the flaw, and are accessing how to fix.  When, I hear from them on the resolution, I'll post it here, also.

Comment: Thanks. If you have the JIRA link to it, that would be great. It is interesting to know what went wrong there. Weird issue.

Comment: There is a private JIRA but not a public JIRA--per Mulesoft.  Mulesoft also didn't have a workaround.  They are working on it though.  i will share what they say when they say it.

Answer (score 0):

This proved to be a Mule bug.  They sent us a patch for it.